# SCCM software install errors

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sccm

I'm having issues with a Win7 x64 client

SCCM2007 R3 / Server 2008 R2 SP1

SCCM thinks that the software is not installing properly (exit code 1) , and hence retries to reinstall due to on fail retry rules.

I've checked the client machine - event logs report success. 
Program itself reports success. 
Program works fine as well.

Is there something that I can set on the client to stop reinstall attempts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but are you just wanting to cancel this one advertisement? If so you can go to the advertisement and disable it which will prevent it from sending out anymore attempts to this one machine. This is assuming the others have already successfully downloaded it.

Also, if you re-scan the computer, it'll read that the software has successfully been installed (should) and depending on how you set up your advertisement, that should also work.

If you want to prevent advertisements to this specific machine in the future you can create a collection that excludes it, but includes all the other machines. Collections are valuable for a organizing your advertisements.

Comment: I don't want to cancel the advertisement, I'm only having this issue on 1 machine out of 50 currently.
But sometimes this happens for software packages.

By default I have software package advertisements – install as soon as possible, and with an assignment of occurs every 1 hour.

Should I not be doing this? Is there somewhere in the SCCM database I can force set a bit to prevent a reinstall attempt for now?

Comment: From what I understand, no. Once you've set the rules of an advertisement, it goes through as is. That means you cannot then make an edit to that advertisement and it will begin to follow those rules. If you wanted to utilize a new set of rules, you'd have to disable the advertisement, edit the rules, and then run it as an advertisement again. As for the one machine failing, what does  exemgr.log say?

Comment: Also, that's why I mentioned re-scanning the machine. If the software is installed, SCCM just doesn't realize it. When it does, the advertisement issue should become a moot point because the agent on the PC will then say, "Oh, I have this, we're good" and the advertisement will be finished.